# How to use search imaplib

Tags: python, datetime, imaplib

I need to download only emails from the IMAP server which are older than a certain Linux timestamp. The Linux time stamp has to be to the second. This gets updated as per the server time.
Example :

```
datetime.now().strftime('%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%s')
'21-Dec-2012 16:50:1356088844
```

Problem code:

```
result, data = imap_server.search(None, '(SINCE '+datetime.now().strftime('%d-%b-%Y')+')')
```

The search function only takes in 'SINCE + DATE'. It won't take a full date time argument. It only takes the date example '21-Dec-2012'

How can I solve this?

Comment: I have a feeling you have to filter on `INTERNALDATE` (or whatever) afterwards - don't think you can give `SINCE` a time...

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that.